# How to generalise a function call to access a templated variable with mulitple types

Tags: c++, function, templates, variables

I have a templated class `sparseSet<T>`, it is an indexed storage class. I have a templated variable to store stuff in `sparseSet<T> components`. I would like to have a series of functions which access the data in the `components` variable, they would recieve pointers to the nth element in the `sparseSet`, you can assume theyre all the same size, eg:

```
function1(foo*, bar*, baz*)
function2(bar*, baz*)
function3(foo*, baz*)
```

You can assume `sparseSet<foo> components` `sparseSet<bar> components` `sparseSet<baz> components` all exist, but they cant be hard coded.
now my question is how am I able to generalise the function call this in such a that I could call a function say `iterateOver()` and pass it the function signature and it will access data from the `components` variable, I thought about using variadic template functions but I dont think that will work, any suggestions?, all help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show some code ([mcve]). The question is not quite clear

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variadic template
like this

```
template<typename ...Arg>
void function1(Arg&& ...arg) // pack the argument
{
   function(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);//unpack and call the relevant function
}
```

you can also read more and see example [here](https://blog.feabhas.com/2014/08/variadic-templates)